# id not working using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, button

Hi everyone i have 3 buttons one is working others not could someone tell me reasons.. in jquery i have commanded it to hide id's which has # in it but middle button which is working and it has 2 id's one with # and one without i take the one without # away it doesnt work.. i am new in programming. sorry my english

< style>

button.rond {   width:50px; height:50px; }

< /style> < /head>

< body> < table id="t01" style="width:750px">

< tr id="#panel6">

```
< td>Coo< /td>  

< td>Fin< /td> < td> < button class="rond" id="#panel6">Stop< /button>< /td>
```

< /tr>

< tr id="panel7">

```
< td>Coo< /td>  

< td>Euro< /td>< td>< button class="rond" id="#panel7">Stop< /button>< /td>
```

< /tr>

< tr id="#panel8">

```
< td>Coo< /td>  

< td>Fin< /td> < td><button class="rond">Stop< /button>< /td>
```

< /tr>
  < /table>
< script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">< /script>

< script>

$(function(){

$('.rond').on('click',function(){

```
var id =$(this).attr('id');

$(id).hide(1);

     });   
});
```

< /script>

< /table>

< /body>

Answer (score 1):

You can get id by `this.id`, also you need to add `#` before id selector. But here there is no need to get id, you can just use `$(this)` instead. Here `this` refers to the clicked dom element.

```
$(function(){    
   $('.rond').on('click',function(){
       $(this).hide();
   });   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery returns only the id of the element it won't provide a `#` include it like this

```
var id =$(this).attr('id');
$('#'+id).hide(1);`
```

Or you can simply use `$(this)` which is a lot easier as @Pranav C Balan suggests